# Do not show blacklisted tags under "Explore Our Questions" for non-logged-in users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, blocked-tags

From the inception of [Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) until about May of this year, the tag "identification-request" was permitted on our site. This led to us accruing around 3500 of these questions total (including deleted questions). [About 400](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentification-request%5D%20deleted%3A0%20is%3Aquestion) are still extant, making this [the third-largest tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags) on our site.

In May 2016, we [blacklisted this tag](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/please-blacklist-the-identification-request-tag-and-lock-all-question-with-the), so no new questions can have this tag. However, because we preserved 400 of these questions (they're all historical-locked), it still shows up as one of the tags that non-logged-in users see on the front page of the site:

[image: red freehand circle]

This is undesirable - we have blacklisted this tag because we don't want people to ask questions with this tag! And if they try, they'll find they can't, which I'm sure is frustrating.

I think it makes sense to hide blacklisted tags from the "Explore Our Questions" section for non-logged-in users, so I am requesting this feature. (Our site is very long-tailed and somewhat slow, so it will be years before the tags ranked 4 through 11 accrue enough questions to bump "identification-request" off the list organically.)

See also: [Remove [identification-request] from front page when not logged in](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3944/) (the same request on our child meta)

Comment: It’s not only the new question speed but also the fact that there is a very large number of animes each with a tag but with very few usages per tag.